# Return Map as json in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

When I return a ModelAndView as json in controller, I will get right value that I want.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Show", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView show(ModelMap mm) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("includes/test");
        return mav;
    }
```

But when I use Map and get in ajax I will get view is empty:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Show", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map show(ModelMap mm) {
        ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView("includes/test");
        Map map=new HashMap();
        String modal="test";
        map.put("view", mav);
        map.put("modal", modal);
        return mav;
    }

    //aJax
    $.ajax(){
        url:'Home/test.html',
        method:'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        success:function(data){
             $('body').append(data['modal']);//Not null, value: test
             $('body').append(data['view']);//Null or empty
        }
    }
```

How can I get right value for view (all html data in this view like",....") when using Map?

Comment: Your dataType is json, so the call is expecting JSON data back, is that what is being sent?

Comment: Sorry. In my controller I will receive json data, but it is unnecessary for this question, so I deleted it. :)

Comment: If you want to return a map, Why are you even creating a ModelAndView?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return your model as json.
You just set your method return type `JsonResult`
and pass your model in return `json();`